# Highchart update categories when adding points

Tags: highcharts

### Background

I was trying to show the average traffic with respect to the hours **DYNAMICALLY** using highchart. That is to say I want it show the traffic repeatedly like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/), when the time comes to 23:00 next I want it back to 0:00.

I am doing this by setting 24 categories ['0:00', '1:00'...,'23:00'], and adding points when the data is updated by ajax, say every 1 second.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  ...//some options
  xAxis: {
            categories:['0:00','1:00','2:00',...,'23:00']
         },
  load: function() {setInterval(updateData,1000)}
  series: [] //empty series here, adding dynamically by ajax
 })
```

the updateData is defined as a function

```
function updateData(){
  var data = $.ajax(...)// get the data
  var series = chart.series[0];
  if(series.data.length < 24){ //when data.length is < 24 add directly
    chart.series[0].addPoint(data,true,false);
  }else{
    chart.series[0].addPoint(data,true,true);//set the 3rd option to true to remove the first data point, actually here this data is equal to the first one since this is a circle, when it comes to 24:00 it is actually 0:00, and I should update the xAxis.
    //code updating the axis categories to [1:00, 2:00...23:00,0:00]
    xAxis.setCategories(categories);
  }
}
```

the x-axis turns out to be [**2:00**, 3:00, ...23:00, 0:00, **24**], That is to say the point that I add this time does NOT correspond to the categories[24]:0:00, It is actually corresponding to the categories[25] which is not exist, so it is set to 24 in default.
[image]

### A solution (quick and dirty)

do not ring shift the categories but push a new circle to it,like:

```
categories.push("time");//time is 0:00-23:00
xAxis.setCategories(categories);
```

but this will make the categories larger and larger..which is bad. 
How can I fix this.

### Another solution(also with some problems)

By using datetime as the type of x-axis, there is another problem. My data format is as follws

```
time              count
8:00               23
9:00               56
...                ...
```

and I can construct Points like [time, count], the question is I have time only. Even if I construct data by manually adding a date like

```
time = (new Date("2012-11-17 "+time)).getTime()
```

seems feasible. But when it got through 24 hours, the spline comes back to the left of the chart since the x-axis value here is equal to the first one. [image]
BTW: how can I make the x-axis show only the time, the image above showed date at the left side, and the time interval is automatically display how to make it display all?
Thank You for your attention!!!

I followed your advice @Ruchit Rami and revised my code:

```
/*update part*/
var time = series.points.length > 0 ? series.points[series.points.length-1].category+3600 : 0;
//from 1970-1-1 0:00 And **add 1 hour everytime**
if (series.data.length < 24) {
series.addPoint([time, sum],true,false);
} else {
series.addPoint([time, sum],true,true);
}
/*chart part*/
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormat: {
      second: '%H:%M',
      minute: '%H:%M',
      hour: '%H:%M',
      day: '%H:%M',
      week: '%H:%M',
      month: '%H:%M',
      year: '%H:%M'
   }
   tickInterval: 3600
}
```

### The result

[image: The date label format seems not affected though I specify it]
The date label format seems not affected though I specify it
[image]
And the time is not correct. Why? Thanks!
[image]
still didnt displayed right

Comment: Try with `tickInterval : 1 * 3600 * 1000`

Comment: Just curious why you data is hourly based and you want it to roll over from 2300 to 0000 and keep plotting out to the right but you do not have the data with a date as well. If you want to plot out data over the time span across all available days why not make one series for each day and draw it on the same chart?

Comment: it is part of my project. The other part of it is a visualization of traffic data on google maps. So it is prefered to be dynamic though it is rolling again and again. @wergeld

Comment: @zoujyjs, so there is a date component but just not important to the charting. Makes sense now. I would however suggest you pass that data into the chart but using Ruchit's solution to only show the actual hour on the xAxis. I would be interested in seeing the final product for this.

Comment: @wergeld but it by default will display the date when the time jumps to the next day at 0:00, shown in the last figure. And when I get through a round at 0:00 2.Jan, it will show again, it's annoying, I am not care about the date, all these data is an average traffic per hour for last few months.

Comment: @zoujyjs, if it is average traffic per hour across a few months then why do you have days rolling over? Why not just average all your data before you send it to HighCharts such that it only goes from 0000 to 2300. One "day's" worth. If you want to show it by week then, again, average it before hand.

Comment: @wergeld One day does worth, but that is a static chart isnt it? from 0000 to 2300, but some animations is shown on google maps, say that the color of all roads will change every 1 hour(1 hour is actually several seconds in my visualization). I want the chart to change accordingly such to highlight current traffic. Is there a solution..

Comment: Now I get it...you want to show avg traffic over time of day...but over N-number of days. I still think this can be done with just a chart from 0000-23000 but instead of all values averaged you adjust the whole series at once for each day. I will try and come up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display only time on the X-axis you can use `dateTimeLabelFormats` property of xaxis and you can use `tickInterval` for setting tick interval on xaxis.

```
 //Sets tickInterval to 24 * 3600 * 1000 if display is by day
                        tickInterval : 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                hour : '%H:%M',
                    day : "%H:%M"        
                }
```

Now, for the issue of chart redraw from the first point, you will need to increase the date of the xaxis point. I am unable to come up with any elegant solution but you can check for time "0:00" while adding new points dynamically and before adding that point increase its date part by one compared to last point in the series.
You can find the last point of the series by `series.points[series.points.length-1]`. 
Hope i haven't missed anything.

Comment: Thanks for help. I followed your advice and edit my question, still having problems~

Comment: got a bug, the unix timestamp is measured in milli seconds..I should add 3600*1000 everytime..Now the time is good by setting interval to 1*3600*1000 but still cant wipe out the date in the left as shown in the last figure.

Comment: hmm...it should be working with `dateTimeLabelFormat` property set.

Comment: but I have set the property </br>`xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormat: {
      second: '%H:%M',
      minute: '%H:%M',
      hour: '%H:%M',
      day: '%H:%M',
      week: '%H:%M',
      month: '%H:%M',
      year: '%H:%M'
   }
   tickInterval: 1*3600*1000
}`

Answer (score 0):

Now, this may not be what you are looking for but I am making some assumptions about what you want to show:

- Data by hour for one "day" 0000-2300
- Do not care to show the date just the time
- Data fluctuates across "days" for a given time

I have created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/cNWTK/) of the chart iterating through 4 "days" of data. I did this by creating an empty data series first to draw the chart, then on load of the chart I iterate through an array of data sets every 1.5 seconds. It then loops back over to the beginning. I have it updating a DIV with what the "day" is. Please let me know if I have missed some condition you need.

Here is the looping code:

```
var data1 = [5, 8, 2, 5, 7, 4, 1, 2, 30, 20, 50, 30, 150, 130, 70, 50, 20, 47, 32, 18, 20, 15, 16, 8];
var data2 = [9, 15, 3, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 60, 75, 112, 190, 267, 365, 258, 164, 168, 190, 47, 16, 20, 18, 5, 8];
var data3 = [15, 18, 12, 5, 7, 4, 1, 2, 130, 20, 150, 130, 150, 130, 70, 50, 20, 47, 32, 18, 20, 15, 16, 8];
var data4 = [19, 15, 13, 4, 11, 11, 0, 0, 60, 175, 112, 190, 267, 365, 258, 164, 168, 190, 47, 16, 20, 18, 15, 18];

var dataSet = [data1, data2, data3, data4];
var dataIter = 0;

$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
            load: function() {
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    if (dataIter >= dataSet.length) dataIter = 0;
                    series.setData(dataSet[dataIter], true);
                    $("#dayLabel").text("Day - " +dataIter.toString());
                    dataIter += 1;
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['0000', '0100', '0200', '0300', '0400', '0500', '0600', '0700', '0800', '0900', '1000', '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600', '1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100', '2200', '2300'],
            labels: {
                rotation: 90
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 500
        },
        series: [{
            data: []}]
    });

});
```